# Monodroid with Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Tags: android, jar, xamarin.android, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to add this Android library (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in my monodroid project.
In Visual Studio 2010 I've created a *Java Bindings Library* project in which I've added the ***jar*** file of that library.

The thing is that when I build my project I get some errors :

```
'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.Impl.LRULimitedMemoryCache.RemoveNext()': return type must be 'Java.Lang.Object' to match overridden member 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.LimitedMemoryCache.RemoveNext()'
```

on this code that the build auto-generated

```
    static IntPtr id_removeNext;
    [Register ("removeNext", "()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;", "GetRemoveNextHandler")]
    protected override global::Android.Graphics.Bitmap RemoveNext ()
    {
        if (id_removeNext == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_removeNext = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "removeNext", "()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");

        if (GetType () == ThresholdType)
            return Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Android.Graphics.Bitmap> (JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod  (Handle, id_removeNext), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
        else
            return Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<global::Android.Graphics.Bitmap> (JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod  (Handle, ThresholdClass, id_removeNext), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
    }
```

And also this error

```
'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.URLConnectionImageDownloader' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.ImageDownloader.GetStreamFromNetwork(Java.Net.URI)'
```

on this line of code

```
 public partial class URLConnectionImageDownloader : global::Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.ImageDownloader
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this problem?
Or has anyone successfully imported this java library in their Monodroid application?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your Transforms\Metadata.xml file

```
<attr path=”/api/package[@name=’com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl’]
/class[@name=’LRULimitedMemoryCache’]
/method[@name=’removeNext’]” name=”managedReturn”>Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

For the second error you can add a partial class definition that implements the method `GetStreamFromNetwork(Java.Net.URI)`

```
namespace Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download {
   partial class URLConnectionImageDownloader{
       public override InputStream GetStreamFromNetwork(Java.Net.URI) {
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Please read this [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29) for more info

Comment: Ok .. thanks. I'm not sure where to add the seconds fix, the one with the partial class

Comment: I've also added the mappings in "Metadata.xml". Now I only get one error    "generator.exe" exited with code -532462766

Comment: Create a new class file in the Bindings project and add the partial class definition. Also try increasing the MSBuild verbosity level to Normal or higher by following these steps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329.aspx

Comment: Tried that. Now I'm getting Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: '/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='FIFOLimitedMemoryCache'/method[@name='removeNext']' has an invalid token. (TaskId:39) Do you have any idea which token is invalid .. and why ?

Comment: The ] was missing from the end of ’LRULimitedMemoryCache’

Comment: Thanks .. that took care of some of the errors Now I'm just left with 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.ImageDownloader' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface and 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.URLConnectionImageDownloader' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.ImageDownloader.GetStreamFromNetwork(Java.Net.URI)'

Comment: I've updated the partial class again. You may need to play around with it, try changing it to protected override, change the return type to Java.Lang.Object, remove the override modifier etc. etc.

Comment: I've edited your answer with the solution that eventually worked for me. I'll mark it as "answered" because you pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: The latest library seems to give a different error now: `/Users/Mike/Projects/AndroidUniversalImage/AndroidUniversalImage/obj/Debug/generated/src/Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.URLConnectionImageDownloader.cs(57,57): Error CS0533: `Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.URLConnectionImageDownloader.GetStreamFromNetwork(Java.Net.URI)' hides inherited abstract member `Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Download.ImageDownloader.GetStreamFromNetwork(Java.Net.URI)' (CS0533) (AndroidUniversalImage)`

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone will be looking for a working binding (as of Universal Image Loader 1.8.4v).

The Transforms\Metadata.xml:

```
<metadata>
  <!-- Binding to universal-image-loader-1.8.4.jar -->
  <!-- We are changing the return types to eliminate errors like 'return type must be 'Java.Lang.Object' to match overridden member' -->
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='FIFOLimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='LargestLimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='LRULimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl']/class[@name='UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache']/method[@name='removeNext']" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
</metadata>
```

And a set of partial classes (placed for example in Additions/Fixes.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

// Fixes to get rid of "does not implement inherited abstract member" errors

namespace Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.Impl
{
    partial class FIFOLimitedMemoryCache
    {
        protected override int GetSize(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return GetSize(value);
        }

        protected override Java.Lang.Ref.Reference CreateReference(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return CreateReference(value);
        }
    }

    partial class LargestLimitedMemoryCache
    {
        protected override int GetSize(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return GetSize(value);
        }

        protected override Java.Lang.Ref.Reference CreateReference(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return CreateReference(value);
        }
    }

    partial class LRULimitedMemoryCache
    {
        protected override int GetSize(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return GetSize(value);
        }

        protected override Java.Lang.Ref.Reference CreateReference(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return CreateReference(value);
        }
    }

    partial class UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache
    {
        protected override int GetSize(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return GetSize(value);
        }

        protected override Java.Lang.Ref.Reference CreateReference(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return CreateReference(value);
        }
    }

    partial class WeakMemoryCache
    {
        protected override Java.Lang.Ref.Reference CreateReference(Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            return CreateReference(value);
        }
    }

    // Fixing ther error 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.Impl.LruMemoryCache' does not implement interface member 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.IMemoryCacheAware.Keys()'. 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.Impl.LruMemoryCache.Keys()' 
    // cannot implement 'Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.IMemoryCacheAware.Keys()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.ICollection'. -->

    partial class LruMemoryCache
    {
        System.Collections.ICollection Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Cache.Memory.IMemoryCacheAware.Keys()
        {
            return (System.Collections.ICollection)Keys();
        }
    }
}

namespace Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.Assist.Deque
{
    partial class LinkedBlockingDeque
    {
        partial class DescendingItr
        {
            public override Java.Lang.Object Next()
            {
                return Next();
            }
        };

        partial class Itr
        {
            public override Java.Lang.Object Next()
            {
                return Next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @krzysztofkarolczak After resolve the error how can you access this lib in xamarin,android

Comment: Hi,can you tell me where i can download armeabi SharedObjects for ImageLoader ? Thanks!